# find indoor navigation routes using beacons

Tags: php, mysql, navigation, beacon, indoor-positioning-system

I have table beacons as below:

```
id| beacon | latitude |longitude
1 |Beacon A| 37.937372|23.965471
2 |Beacon B| 37.981244|23.948077
3 |Beacon C| 37.991272|23.967873
4 |Beacon D| 37.937372|23.948681
5 |Beacon E| 37.868695|23.597659
```

Another table mapping

```
beacon_id|mapping_beacon_id
1        |2
1        |3
.
.
and so on..
```

[refer diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkCzk.png)

suppose i have two beacon points Beacon A , Beacon J and now i have to find out routes of combination towards beacon J with help of mapping. Am not able to find routes of combination. i have tried using Haversine formula but not able to get result. 
Language prefer : php 
Database : mysql

Comment: Nice, an np-complete problem. I think it's Djikstra that you're after.

Comment: Incidentially, Beacon E is nowhere near the others.

Comment: thank you @Strawberry, Dijkstra algorithm can work.